# Null Pointer Exception after migrating project to gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting the following error after migrating my project to gradle.  I'm not sure why this is occurring and this was working before migrating.  I tried copying files to a entirely new project built from grandle build package from the ground up and now I'm having these problems.

```
Process: com.hospital.headling.hospital, PID: 5243
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.hospital.headling.hospital/com.hospital.headling.hospital.ListViewActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempinvoke virtual method 'void com.hospital.headling.hospital.util.ExpandableHeightGridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.hospital.headling.hospital.util.ExpandableHeightGridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
at com.hospital.headling.hospital.ListViewActivity.setAdapters(ListViewActivity.java:127)
at com.hospital.headling.hospital.ListViewActivity.onCreate(ListViewActivity.java:61)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

ListViewActivity.java

```
    package com.hospital.headling.hospital;

    import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import com.hospital.headling.hospital.adapter.CustomAdapter;
    import com.hospital.headling.hospital.util.ExpandableHeightGridView;

    import org.apache.commons.lang3.ArrayUtils;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class ListViewActivity extends Activity {

        private ExpandableHeightGridView gridView;
        private ListView listView;


        //drawables array for gridview
        private static final int[] osImage = { R.drawable.cardiac, R.drawable.ortho,
                R.drawable.neuro, R.drawable.cancer, R.drawable.doctors, R.drawable.services,
                R.drawable.visit, R.drawable.careers, R.drawable.bills, R.drawable.email, R.drawable.about };

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            ArrayList<String> menu_links = new ArrayList<>();
            menu_links.add("Cardiac");
            menu_links.add("Orthopedic");
            menu_links.add("Neurosciences");
            menu_links.add("Cancer");
            menu_links.add("Find A Doctor");
            menu_links.add("Medical Services");
            menu_links.add("Patients and Visitors");
            menu_links.add("Careers");
            menu_links.add("Pay Your Bill");
    // Find a reference to the {@link ListView} in the layout
            ListView companiesListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    // Create a new {@link ArrayAdapter} of the menu_links
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, menu_links);


    // Set the adapter on the {@link ListView}
    // so the list can be populated in the user interface
            companiesListView.setAdapter(adapter);


            ///end of stuff


            setAdapters();

            //start
            companiesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    switch (position) {
                /*  case 0:  Intent Cardiac = new Intent(this, Cardiac.class);
                        startActivity(Cardiac);
                        break;
                    case 1:  Intent Orthopedic = new Intent(this, Orthopedic.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;
                    case 2:  Intent Neurosciences = new Intent(this, Neurosciences.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;
                    case 3:  Intent Cancer = new Intent(this, Cancer.class);
                        startActivity(FindADoctor);
                        break;
                    case 4:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, reservetickets.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;
                    case 4:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, reservetickets.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;
                    case 4:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, reservetickets.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break;
                    case 4:  Intent newActivity = new Intent(this, reservetickets.class);
                        startActivity(newActivity);
                        break; */
                        case 9:
                            Intent ContactForm = new Intent(ListViewActivity.this, com.hospital.headling.hospital.ContactForm.class);
                            startActivity(ContactForm);
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });
            //finish

        }

        /**
         * set footer for listview (it's a gridview)
         */
        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        private void addGridViewAsListViewFooter() {
            View footer = (View) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_gridview, null);
            listView.addFooterView(footer);

            gridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) footer.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

            // set expand to show all gridview rows
            gridView.setExpanded(true);
        }


        /**
         * set adapters for list view and gridview
         */
        private void setAdapters() {
            // convert int array to Integer array by apache common lang library
            Integer[] osImageList = ArrayUtils.toObject(osImage);

            // set gridview adapter
            CustomAdapter gridViewAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, R.layout.item_grid, R.id.image, osImageList);

            gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);

        }
    }
```

ExampleHeightGridView.java

```
package com.hospital.headling.hospital.util;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class ExpandableHeightGridView extends GridView {

    boolean expanded = false;

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public ExpandableHeightGridView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public boolean isExpanded() {
        return expanded;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        if (isExpanded()) {
            // Calculate entire height by providing a very large height hint.
            // MEASURED_SIZE_MASK represents the largest height possible.
            int expandSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(MEASURED_SIZE_MASK, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, expandSpec);

            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = getLayoutParams();
            params.height = getMeasuredHeight();
        } else {
            super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        }
    }

    public void setExpanded(boolean expanded) {
        this.expanded = expanded;
    }
}
```

layout_gridview.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <com.healinghospital.healinghospital.util.ExpandableHeightGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:numColumns="6"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"/>

    <!--<TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#000099"
        android:text="@string/corporation"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" /> -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#000099"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


</LinearLayout>
```

activity_mail.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
package com.hospital.headling.hospital.adapter;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.hospital.headling.hospital.R;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {

    private Activity activity;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, int textViewResourceId, Integer[] osimage) {
        super(activity, resource, textViewResourceId, osimage);
        this.activity = activity;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        // inflate layout from xml
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // If holder not exist then locate all view from UI file.
        if (convertView == null) {
            // inflate UI from XML file
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid, parent, false);
            // get all UI view
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            // set tag for holder
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            // if holder created, get tag from view
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.image.setImageResource(getItem(position));

        return convertView;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView image;

        public ViewHolder(View v) {
            image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.image);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Next time please do not post all the xml and java code in your question (it takes lots of time to read everything). You should understand the problem by the first logcat message: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempinvoke virtual method 'void com.hospital.headling.hospital.util.ExpandableHeightGridView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference

Comment: Gradle doesn't cause NullPointerExceptions within your own code, just so you know.

Comment: @HonorLT The XML and some Java code is necessary (because the ID could be missing from the XML, which would result in it as null). However, a [mcve] (keyword of minimal), would be nice

Comment: @cricket_007 that's exactly what I wanted to say but because of my poor english didn't manage to express my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You never calls the method `addGridViewAsListViewFooter()` which initialize your `ExpandableHeightGridView`.

```
gridView = (ExpandableHeightGridView) footer.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
```

So in this line:

```
gridView.setAdapter(gridViewAdapter);
```

here `gridView` is never initialized and so it gives a `NullPointerException`

initialize it before calling `setAdapter()`